# Custom Master page for Sharepoint hosted APP

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a custom master page. I want this master page to be applied for an app (SharePoint hosted). The app contains an aspx page (Default.aspx).

By default, the Default.aspx inherits the master page as below:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
    MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>
```

When I add reference to inherit seattle.Master as below - the seattle.master is perfectly applied to the app:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
    MasterPageFile="~site/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master"Language="C#" %>
```

Same way, if I apply my custom master page (below is the code), it doesn't work. The app throws File Not Found error.

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
    MasterPageFile="~site/_catalogs/masterpage/Custom.master"Language="C#" %>
```

Note: The seattle.Master and Custom.Master (copy of the Seattle master page) are in the same location.

Many articles suggesting us to create a module with master page and deploy. (http://anthony-verschraegen.blogspot.com/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-apps-custom-app-master.html?_sm_au_=iVVRQfD1Zms2VTZr)

My question here is why we need a module when there is a master page in /_catalogs/masterpage location?

I have to reuse the custom master page in multiple SharePoint hosted apps.

Please suggest

Comment: Spelling; layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer seattle.Master master page, it works because this master page in the app web. You can do a test, modify the seattle.Master in the Host Web and check if the add-in apply or not.

Your custom master page in the host web, so it not works in add-in.

So, we need create a module with master page, it will deploy the master page into app web.